# Redux Toolkit / Jest / renderHook / testing the function returned by a hook with providers

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

So i have a hook, called useNavigation, it returns a function called navigateForwards. It handles the page validation etc - given it interacts with various providers like redux and context the hook needs wrapping and that state provided - and variable on a test by test case.

What do i need to do to make that happen? I have a helper like this for components, i want something similar for hooks.

```
const renderWithProviders = (
  component,
  {
    reduxState = {}, // all passing of data to the providers (maybe a mock initial state in tests)
    store = setupStore(reduxState), // redux store mock - should be recreated in each test
    stateProviderProps = defaultStateProviderProps({
      formSettings: initialState(),
    }), // context props (not its state)
    mockedProviderProps = { mocks: [], addTypename: false }, // i.e. default props for context provider
    ...renderOptions // allow addition to the render function
  } = {}
) => {
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {/* TODO don't forget to remove StateProvider - i.e. context from here when redux is done, it is echoed as stateProviderProps function was created that way and changing means changing all tests */}
        <StateProvider {...stateProviderProps}>
          <MockedProvider {...mockedProviderProps}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={themes.chameleon}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
          </MockedProvider>
        </StateProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  };

  // Return an object with the store and all of RTL's query functions
  return {
    store,
    ...render(component, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }),
  };
};
```

This is how it is called.

```
    renderWithProviders(<BrowserMessages />, {
      stateProviderProps: {
        formSettings: initialState(),
      },
      reduxState: {
        optionalFormConfig: { iFrameId: undefined },
      },
    });
```

This is how i see it happening for hooks

```
export const renderHookWithProviders = (
  hook,
  {
    reduxState = {}, // all passing of data to the providers (maybe a mock initial state in tests)
    store = setupStore(reduxState), // redux store mock - should be recreated in each test
    stateProviderProps = defaultStateProviderProps({
      formSettings: initialState(),
    }), // context props (not its state)
    mockedProviderProps = { mocks: [], addTypename: false }, // i.e. default props for context provider
    ...renderHookOptions // allow addition to the render function
  } = {}
) => {
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {/* TODO don't forget to remove StateProvider - i.e. context from here when redux is done, it is echoed as stateProviderProps function was created that way and changing means changing all tests */}
        <StateProvider {...stateProviderProps}>
          <MockedProvider {...mockedProviderProps}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={themes.chameleon}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
          </MockedProvider>
        </StateProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  };

  // Return an object with the store and all of RTL's query functions
  return {
    store,
    ...renderHook(hook, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderHookOptions }),
  };
};
```

Being called like this

```
        const { store, result } = renderHookWithProviders(
          () => useNavigationHook,
          {
            stateProviderProps: {
              formSettings: initialState(),
            },
            reduxState: {
              paging: mockPaging(),
              components: mockComponents(),
              navigation: mockNavigation(),
            },
          }
        );

        act(() => {
          result.current();
        });
```

Now we have result.current which appears as a function "useNavigation", but when i call it (hoping it is wrapped with providers and in a wrap component). I get a must call hooks within a function component error.... help / thank you!

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, what are `StateProvider`, `MockedProvider` etc...?

Comment: @slideshowp2 its a commercial app, so can't do that sadly, StateProvider is context and MockedProvider is apollo (yeah i know redux, context and apollo are all in use on this app - too many state providers).